# How can I create a dynamic href by async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do I get `[object Promise]`? I want to get the URL returned by the function `getUrl`.

This is my code:

```
<Link href={getUrl()}>
  'show show show'
</Link>

const getUrl = async () => { 
  return await getUrltoGo()
}
```

In that function I need to do `await` request to my database.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom component that handles this, here's an example using hooks ( customize it to match your needs or use a class if hooks are not available )

```
const AyncLink = ({text}) => {
    const [href, setHref] = useState('')

    useEffect(async () => {
        const url = await getUrltoGo();
        setHref(url)
    }, [text])

    return <Link href={href}>{text}</Link>
}
```

usage :

```
<AsyncLink text="show show show" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why do I get [object Promise]?**

The `getUrl` function is equivalent to:

```
const getUrl = () => Promise.resolve(url);

// or
const getUrl = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(url));
```

**How can I make it work?**

You can store the url in a state that is asynchronously updated:

```
function Comp() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('/#');

  useEffect(()=> getUrl().then(setUrl));

  return (<Link href={url}>'show show show'</Link>);
}
```